# Итерация в словарях

Tags: python, словари, for, dict

```py
myLoot = {
    "gold": 17,
 "ser": 2,
  "bronze":1,
   "mech": 2
   }
lootDragon = ['a','s','d']

def addLoot(inventory, addInventory):
    for i in addInventory:
        inventory[i] = inventory.get(i, 0) +1
    return inventory   

print(addLoot(myLoot, lootDragon))
```

Мы прогоняем i по списку addInventory
Затем мне не понятная эта строчка

```py
inventory[i] = inventory.get(i, 0) +1
```

в плане:

1. я понимаю что она ищет похожие ключи, но я не понимаю алгоритм по которому она работает. Для меня код после фора выглядит так после первой итерации

```py
inventory['а'] = inventory.get('а', 0) +1
```

Объясните пж, я хочу понять это изнутри что бы двигаться дальше

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```py
inventory[i] = inventory.get(i, 0) + 1
```

Метод `get` получает из словаря элемент с ключом `i`, а если такого нет, то возвращает `0`, поскольку он тут указан вторым аргументом (без указания аргумента возвращается `None`).

Таким образом получается, что если элемента с ключом `i` в словаре нет, то `inventory.get(i, 0)` вернёт `0`, а если элемент есть, то вернётся текущее значение. Затем к тому, что получено через `get` добавляется `1`. Вот и получается, что если элемент уже был, то он увеличится на `1`, а если элемента не было в словаре, то он появится со значением `1`. Таким образом организуется счётчик.

Более понятно этот код можно развернуть в такой, полностью аналогичный по логике:

```py
if i in inventory:
    inventory[i] += 1
else:
    inventory[i] = 1
```

Просто запись через `get` получается короче и в одну строку.

P.S. Есть ещё более короткий вариант - с использованием `defaultdict`:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

myLoot = defaultdict(int, {
    "gold": 17,
    "ser": 2,
    "bronze":1,
    "mech": 2
})
lootDragon = ['a','s','d']

def addLoot(inventory, addInventory):
    for i in addInventory:
        inventory[i] += 1
    return inventory

print(dict(addLoot(myLoot, lootDragon)))
```

В этом варианте вообще не нужно заботиться об инициализации счётчика, `defaultdict` сам её сделает, использовав значение по умолчанию для переданного ему первым аргументом типа.